# After installing Phyton3.6 , Terminal won't see it. Why?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

After installing Phyton 3.6 , I can't get Terminal to find it . I am trying to learn Phyton and very new at this. Please help with details instructions. Thanks

This is what I get:

```
Last login: Fri Dec 22 08:24:04 on console
Carmens-MacBook-Pro:~ Clp$ phyton
-bash: phyton: command not found
Carmens-MacBook-Pro:~ Clp$ phyton3 --version
-bash: phyton3: command not found
Carmens-MacBook-Pro:~ Clp$
```

Comment: @Allan not a duplicate this us either  new app or a misspelling.

Answer (score 11):

The software is called `python` not phyton. For Python 3, run `python3`.

Comment: I'm not really convinced: even phyton.org errr... python.org itself mentions [phyton](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nester_mfb/1.3.0) or [Python-Dev Which version is better? Phyton 27 or Phyton 35?](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2016-April/143617.html)! ;-)

Comment: thank you ! I just realized my mistake. Guess it was a long night.

Comment: @klanomath That's a mailing list, not official documentation.

Comment: @Kreiri klanomath is speaking in jest! Have another look at what’s actually being discussed in the mailing list message :)

Comment: Some people here should pour themselves a nice long drink ;)